# Change user status from 0 to 1 after 6 months

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change the user status from 0 to 1 after 6 months. I have two date columns in my abc table i.e. reg_date and exp_date in which reg_date contains the date&time of registration and exp_date contains the date&time of expiry which is 6 months after of registration. I just want to change user status from 0 to 1 automatically when the current date matches with exp_date.

Here is my query :-

```
$reg_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); 
$exp_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+6 month'));
```

Is this possible with any conditions, if possible please help me out.

Comment: You could create and event which would run daily to do this. But status seems like a redundant field , you know when it's expired.

Comment: is your table values from database?

Comment: Why do you want to change it in the database rather then compute it in the code by means of a function based on the date of registration?

Comment: yes, @comphonia

Comment: i am not getting you, can you explain more @jotaen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to change user status from 0 to 1 automatically when the current date matches with exp_date.

Seems like you want :

```
UPDATE abc SET status = 1 WHERE exp_date < NOW();
```

Rather than checking specifically for the current date, this will reset all users that ever expired.

If you want to disable only users that expired today :

```
UPDATE abc SET status = 1 WHERE DATE(exp_date) = CUR_DATE();
```